# not able to load bundle

Tags: iphone, ios

i am trying to load a bundle with the help of `NSBundle` object 
but this bundle is not loading into the main bundle 
code :

```
NSBundle *bundle= [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone_bundle" ofType:@"bundle"]];
        [bundle load];
       NSLog(@"%d",[bundle load]);
```

the name of bundle is `iphone_bundle`

Answer (score 0):

You can use resources from your bundle as shown below..

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_bundle.bundle/someImage.png"];
```